# Is there a way to lint the Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

If a Dockerfile is written with mistakes for example:

`CMD ["service", "--config", "/etc/service.conf]` (missing quote)

Is there a way to lint it to detect such mistake before building?

Comment: https://github.com/redhataccess/dockerfile_lint

Comment: I use very successfully in Buddy pipeline [dockerfile-lint](https://github.com/buddy-works/dockerfile-linter#readme). Dockerfile lint action should always come as the first action in pipelines. Some of the rules were inspired by Dockerfile documentation. Configuration is very simple and involves selecting the Dockerfile from the filesystem.

Answer (score 32):

Try:

- Either the [Haskell Dockerfile Linter ("hadolint")](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint), also [available online](https://hadolint.github.io/hadolint/). `hadolint` parses the Dockerfile into an AST and performs checking and validation based on [best practice Docker images rules](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/). It also uses [Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) to lint the Bash code on `RUN` commands.
- Or [dockerlinter](https://github.com/RedCoolBeans/dockerlint) (node.js-based).

I've performed a simple test against of a simple Docker file with `RUN`, `ADD`, `ENV` and `CMD`. `dockerlinter` was smart about grouping the same violation of rules together but it was not able to inspect as thorough as `hadolinter` possibly due to the lack of `Shellcheck` to statically analyze the Bash code.

Although `dockerlinter` falls short in the scope it can lint, it does seem to be *much easier* to install. `npm install -g dockerlinter` will do, while compiling `hadolinter` requires a Haskell compiler and build environment that takes forever to compile.

```
$ hadolint ./api/Dockerfile
L9 SC2046 Quote this to prevent word splitting.
L11 SC2046 Quote this to prevent word splitting.
L8 DL3020 Use COPY instead of ADD for files and folders
L10 DL3020 Use COPY instead of ADD for files and folders
L13 DL3020 Use COPY instead of ADD for files and folders
L18 DL3020 Use COPY instead of ADD for files and folders
L21 DL3020 Use COPY instead of ADD for files and folders
L6 DL3008 Pin versions in apt get install. Instead of `apt-get install <package>` use `apt-get install <package>=<version>`
L6 DL3009 Delete the apt-get lists after installing something
L6 DL3015 Avoid additional packages by specifying `--no-install-recommends`

$ dockerlint ./api/Dockerfile
WARN:  ADD instruction used instead of COPY on line 8, 10, 13, 18, 21
ERROR: ./api/Dockerfile failed.
```

*Update in 2018*. Since `hadolint` has the official Docker repository now, you can get the executable quickly:

```
id=$(docker create hadolint/hadolint:latest)
docker cp "$id":/bin/hadolint .
docker rm "$id"
```

or you can use this command

```
docker container run --rm -i hadolint/hadolint hadolint - < Dockerfile
```

This is a statically compiled executable (according to `ldd hadolint`), so it should run regardless of installed libraries. A reference on how the executable is built: https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/blob/master/docker/Dockerfile.

Comment: @LuísBianchin Yes, it's made available by the same author - as long as you trust pasting your Dockerfile to a 3rd party, sure.

Comment: @Devy why wouldn't you trust it? Do you store secrets inside `Dockerfile` itself?

Comment: You can download hadolint executables from [its release page](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/releases). On macOS, hadolint also can be installed using Homebrew: `brew install hadolint`

Answer (score 3):

If you have a RedHat subscription, you can access the "Linter for Dockerfile" application directly at https://access.redhat.com/labs/linterfordockerfile/; information about the application is located at https://access.redhat.com/labsinfo/linterfordockerfile

This Node.js application is also available on GitHub https://github.com/redhataccess/dockerfile_lint if you prefer to run it locally.

Answer (score 2):

I use very successfully in my CI pipeline npm's [dockerfile_lint](https://github.com/projectatomic/dockerfile_lint). You can add or extend rules. Using the `package.json` you can create different configs for the different jobs. There are both

Docker CLI

```
docker run -it --rm --privileged -v `pwd`:/root/ \
         projectatomic/dockerfile-lint \
         dockerfile_lint [-f Dockerfile]

docker run -it --rm --privileged -v `pwd`:/root/  \
         -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
         projectatomic/dockerfile-lint \       
         dockerfile_lint  image <imageid>
```

and Atomic CLI available

```
 atomic run projectatomic/dockerfile-lint

 atomic run projectatomic/dockerfile-lint image <imageid>
```

Also you can lint your images for tagging.

Answer (score 2):

I created [dockerfile-validator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=marquesmps.dockerfile-validator) as an extension for VS Code, which uses the [dockerfile-lint](https://github.com/projectatomic/dockerfile_lint) mentioned in a previous answer. By default it uses dockerfile-lint default rules, but in VS code User Settings (dockerfile-validator.rulefile.path) you can specify a path to a custom rule file with your own coding standards.

Answer (score 1):

Recently, I cam across [dockerfilelint](https://github.com/replicatedhq/dockerfilelint) which is NodeJS based.

`dockerfilelint Dockerfile`

Supports following rules and rudimentary [CMD checks](https://github.com/replicatedhq/dockerfilelint#cmd)

```
required_params
uppercase_commands
from_first
invalid_line
sudo_usage
apt-get_missing_param
apt-get_recommends
apt-get-upgrade
apt-get-dist-upgrade
apt-get-update_require_install
apkadd-missing_nocache_or_updaterm
apkadd-missing-virtual
invalid_port
invalid_command
expose_host_port
label_invalid
missing_tag
latest_tag
extra_args
missing_args
add_src_invalid
add_dest_invalid
invalid_workdir
invalid_format
apt-get_missing_rm
deprecated_in_1.13
```

Hadolint seems like a better option but this may suffice for simple needs. Also, Github's [super-linter](https://github.com/github/super-linter) uses this.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not too familiar with `go` but it looks like you can simply call the [Parse](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/640e0fc578e5acdaa71216a300396dfa9af8054f/builder/parser/parser.go) method as is done in the test suite [here](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/640e0fc578e5acdaa71216a300396dfa9af8054f/builder/parser/parser_test.go). If that does not return an err then your lint passes. I'm assuming that's trivial to expose to a script or something to call during development.