# Leading spaces inside Dockerfile for readability

Tags: docker, dockerfile, linter

Am I able to use indentation in a `Dockerfile`?

Is there anything wrong with using spaces for indenting like this?

```
FROM python:3.8-buster
  RUN pip --no-cache-dir install poetry gunicorn

  WORKDIR /app
    COPY poetry.toml pyproject.toml poetry.lock /app/
    RUN poetry export --dev -f requirements.txt > requirements.txt
    RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

  WORKDIR /app/src
    COPY src /app/src
    RUN ./manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear

  CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":8000", "wsgi:application"]
```

Building such docker image seems to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can indent lines in Dockerfile, but usually it's used only when breaking long command lines, like:

```
RUN export ADMIN_USER="mark" \
    && echo $ADMIN_USER > ./mark \
    && unset ADMIN_USER
```

You can use indenting for instructions, but i, personally, wouldn't do that -- each instruction creates new layer and it's logical to place them with equal indent. As extra indenting like:

```
FROM python:3.8-buster
  RUN pip --no-cache-dir install poetry gunicorn
```

would look like it introduces sub-layers(and Docker doesn't have  such concept).

But again, that's personal, and if you and your team agrees on that formatting standard -- there's a bunch of linters that would allow you to use any formatting standard with little(or no) tweaking:

- [Haskell Dockerfile Linter](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint) -- [check it online](https://hadolint.github.io/hadolint/)
- [FROM:latest](https://github.com/replicatedhq/dockerfilelint) -- [check it online](https://www.fromlatest.io/#/)
- [dockerfile-lint](https://github.com/projectatomic/dockerfile_lint)

Answer (score 2):

## Format of `Dockerfile`

`Dockerfile` [format requirements](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#format) are pretty concise:

> Here is the format of the `Dockerfile`:
>
> ```
> # Comment
> INSTRUCTION arguments
> ```
>
> The instruction is not case-sensitive. However, convention is for them to be UPPERCASE to distinguish them from arguments more easily.

There isn't any suggestions on line indentation.

## Use linters

There are many `Dockerfile` linters, so general answer is: always try to lint your development process.

- `NPM`-based [dockerfile_lint](https://github.com/projectatomic/dockerfile_lint) by [projectatomic](https://github.com/projectatomic). It's a former [redhataccess](https://github.com/redhataccess/) project. If you have a RedHat account, you can try it [online](https://access.redhat.com/labs/linterfordockerfile/)
- `Node.js`-based [dockerfile-linter](https://github.com/buddy-works/dockerfile-linter) by [buddy-works](https://github.com/buddy-works)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34752050/5720818) says:

> - Either the [Haskell Dockerfile Linter ("hadolint")](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint). `hadolint` parses the Dockerfile into an AST and performs checking and validation based on [best practice Docker images rules](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/). It also uses [Shellcheck](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck) to lint the Bash code on `RUN` commands.

- Or [dockerlinter](https://github.com/RedCoolBeans/dockerlint) (node.js-based).
- `hadolint` available online: https://hadolint.github.io/hadolint/
- Yet another linter: [GitHub - replicatedhq/dockerfilelint: An opinionated Dockerfile linter.](https://github.com.cnpmjs.org/replicatedhq/dockerfilelint)
- Online version:  https://www.fromlatest.io

## Let's check your `Dockerfile` with linters

#### `FROM:latest`

[`FROM:latest`](https://www.fromlatest.io/) says:

> No problems or suggestions found!

#### `hadolint`:

[`hadolint`](https://hadolint.github.io/hadolint/) says:

> - [Pin versions in pip. Instead of `pip install <package>` use `pip install <package>==<version>`](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/wiki/DL3013)
> - [Make sure not to read and write the same file in the same pipeline.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2094)